# os.path.isdir() returns false on unaccessible, but existing directory

Tags: python, unix

Lets say I have directories like:

`foo/bar/`

`bar` is `chmod 777` and `foo` is 000.

When I call `os.path.isdir('foo/bar')` it returns just False, without any Permission Denied Exception or anything, why is it like that? Shouldn't it return True?

Comment: Could you accept my answer if it helped you? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not root then you cannot access foo. Therefore you can't check if foo/bar exists and it returns False because it cannot find a directory with that name (as it cannot access the parent directory).

Answer (score 2):

`os.path.isdir` can return `True` or `False`, but cannot raise an exception.

So if the directory cannot be accessed (because parent directory doesn't have traversing rights), it returns `False`.

If you want an exception, try using `os.chdir` or `os.listdir` that are designed to raise exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a `try/except` block:

```
import os

path = '/foo/bar'

if os.path.exists(path):
    try:
        os.chdir(path)
    except PermissionError:
        print ("Access Denied To:", path)
```